# Using PR_SET_NAME from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, rhel7

I've been using the following code for a while:

```py
import ctypes
me = ctypes.CDLL(None)
me.prctl(15, "meow", 0, 0, 0)
```

With Python-2.6 on RHEL6 this works, changing process name to "meow".

With Python-3.7 on RHEL7, however, after going through same code, the process name becomes "m" -- just the first letter of the string.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ctypes `prctl` is probably expecting 8-bit strings, and in Python 3 you're now passing Unicode.   Try `me.prctl(15, b"meow", 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Sigh, yes, this is it... Of course, so many C-functions expect Unicode strings, Python could not do the conversion automatically...

Comment: @MikhailT. If you set `me.prctl.argtypes = c_int,c_char_p,c_int,c_int,c_int` (or whatever the C function types are specifically) then `ctypes` would at least give a "wrong type" error message.  Python/ctypes *does* do an automatic conversion to `wchar_t*` for a Unicode string...but without knowing what argtype the function required, it can't know it was wrong.